# OpenCV cvMatchTemplate same image size

Tags: opencv

I currently trying to find the Normalized Cross Correlation between two 1-by-1 images. So in order to do this, I'm using cvMatchTemplate. But after using cvMinMaxLoc, maxval always returns 1.00000 for any 2 1-by-1 images.

So I tried to bypass this by trying to use cvMatchTemplate on a 6-by-3 image and a 3-by-3 image. For each original pixel, I expanded it out into a 6-by-3 and a 3-by-3 to see if this would provide better results. It doesn't. maxval still returns 1.000000. Is there a better way to find the NCC between 2 pixels?

```
            cvSetImageROI(img, cvRect(curWidth, curHeight, 1, 1));
            IplImage* tempROI = cvCreateImage(cvSize(1, 1), img->depth, img->nChannels);
            cvCopy(img, tempROI);
            cvResetImageROI(img);

            IplImage* currentROI = cvCreateImage(cvSize(6,3), img->depth, img->nChannels);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    cvSetImageROI(currentROI, cvRect(j, i, 1, 1));
                    cvCopy(tempROI, currentROI);
                    cvResetImageROI(currentROI);
                }
            }

            cvReleaseImage(&tempROI);
            cvSetImageROI(opp_img, cvRect(opp_loc, curHeight, 1, 1));
            tempROI = cvCreateImage(cvSize(1, 1), opp_img->depth, opp_img->nChannels);
            cvCopy(opp_img, tempROI);
            cvResetImageROI(opp_img);

            IplImage* centerROI = cvCreateImage(cvSize(3,3), opp_img->depth, opp_img->nChannels);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    cvSetImageROI(centerROI, cvRect(j, i, 1, 1));
                    cvCopy(tempROI, centerROI);
                    cvResetImageROI(centerROI);
                }
            }
            IplImage *re = cvCreateImage(cvSize(4, 1), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
            cvZero(re);
            cvMatchTemplate(currentROI, centerROI, re, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
            cvMinMaxLoc(re, &minval, &maxval, &minloc, &maxloc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do NCC on 1-by-1 images or any images with same image size, but it is not useful usually. If you search a template T in an image I, the result would be R with dimensions I - T + 1 , so if the images are the same size, the result is 1x1. If you search for minmax location in any image with that size(1x1) , it will return 1.000 as expected.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my question. maxval returns 1.0000 not maxloc. Does this change anything or does 1.000 still intuitively make sense? I'm expected maxval to be in the range between -1 and 1 if I'm comparing two 1-by-1 images.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the math behind normalized cross-correlation. You will find that in the case of 1*1 images you will ALWAYS get 1.0 NCC - the main idea of NCC is to ignore intensity differences.
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/object_detection.html